# Communication between windows service and WPF with self-hosted owin web api

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-web-api, owin

I need to make a WPF application running under a regular account and a windows service that will run under the admin account. The WPF application will call a service that then performs the required tasks.

What I'm dealing with is the way of communication between these two elements. Mostly I came across references to WCF and named pipes with which I do not have much experience.

So I thought I would create a self-hosting owin web api and use it instead of WCF.

I would therefore like to ask what are the disadvantages of such a solution. Is the use of a self-hosted web api suitable for such purposes, or I would rather use WCF named pipes.

Thanks for any advice :-)

Comment: It depends on the type, size and amount of messages to be send. Both will probably do. We did use a self hosted web api for our winforms client communications with a windows service and it does its job. I suppose WCF can be more efficient in certain scenario's and is not http(s) only. It supports full duplex communications if needed.

Comment: I finally used WCF with named pipes.